# Control y-axis in violins package

Tags: r, plot

Is there any way to either disable the y-axis in the `violins` package plot command (`yaxt="n"` doesn't work) or specify it?

```
library(violins)
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(100,0,1),y=rnorm(100,1,1),z=rnorm(100,2,3))
violins(df,yaxt="n")
Error in violins(df, yaxt = "n") : unused argument (yaxt = "n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to rewrite the function to something like this:

```
violins_ <- function (x, by, range = 1.5, h = NULL, ylim = NULL, names = NULL, 
                      horizontal = FALSE, col = "transparent", border = "black", 
                      lty = 1, lwd = 1, rectCol = "grey50", colMed = "grey80", 
                      pchMed = 19, at, add = FALSE, wex = 1, drawRect = TRUE, main = "", 
                      xlab = "", ylab = "", connect = c("median", "mean", "hubermu", 
                                                        "deciles"), SD.or.SE = c("SD"), connectcol = c("lightblue", 
                                                                                                       "cyan", "darkred", "grey"), las = 2, stats = FALSE, quantiles = c(0.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                         0.9), CImed = TRUE, deciles = TRUE) 

{

  options(warnings = -1)
  require(sm)
  if (is.data.frame(x)) 
    x <- as.list.data.frame(x)
  if (!missing(by)) {
    if (is.numeric(by)) 
      x <- .cat2list(x[order(by)], sort(by))
    if (!is.numeric(by)) 
      x <- .cat2list(x, by)
  }
  if (is.list(x)) {
    datas <- x
    if (length(names) == 0) 
      names <- names(x)
  }
  else {
    datas <- list(x)
  }
  n <- length(datas)
  if (missing(at)) 
    at <- 1:n
  upper <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  lower <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  q.1 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  q1 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  q3 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  q.9 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  med <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  hubermu <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  average <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  stddevlower <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  stddevupper <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  stderrlower <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  stderrupper <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  base <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
  height <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
  medCI05 <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
  medCI95 <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
  decile <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = 9)
  baserange <- c(Inf, -Inf)
  args <- list(display = "none")
  if (!(is.null(h))) 
    args <- c(args, h = h)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    data <- (datas[[i]])
    data.min <- min(data, na.rm = TRUE)
    data.max <- max(data, na.rm = TRUE)
    q.1[i] <- quantile(data, quantiles[1], na.rm = TRUE)
    q1[i] <- quantile(data, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
    q3[i] <- quantile(data, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)
    q.9[i] <- quantile(data, quantiles[2], na.rm = TRUE)
    med[i] <- median(data, na.rm = TRUE)
    medCI05[i] <- caroline:::.ci.median(data)$ci[2]
    medCI95[i] <- caroline:::.ci.median(data)$ci[3]
    hubermu[i] <- caroline:::.huber.mu(data)
    average[i] <- mean(data)
    iqd <- q3[i] - q1[i]
    upper[i] <- min(q3[i] + range * iqd, data.max)
    lower[i] <- max(q1[i] - range * iqd, data.min)
    stddevlower[i] <- average[i] - sd(data)
    stddevupper[i] <- average[i] + sd(data)
    if (deciles) 
      for (j in 1:9) decile[i, j] <- quantile(data, j/10)
    N <- length(data)
    stderrlower[i] <- average[i] - (sd(data)/sqrt(N))
    stderrupper[i] <- average[i] + (sd(data)/sqrt(N))
    est.xlim <- c(min(lower[i], data.min), max(upper[i], 
                                               data.max))
    smout <- do.call("sm.density", c(list(data, xlim = est.xlim), 
                                     args))
    hscale <- 0.4/max(smout$estimate) * wex
    base[[i]] <- smout$eval.points
    height[[i]] <- smout$estimate * hscale
    t <- range(base[[i]])
    baserange[1] <- min(baserange[1], t[1])
    baserange[2] <- max(baserange[2], t[2])
  }
  if (!add) {
    xlim <- if (n == 1) 
      at + c(-0.5, 0.5)
    else range(at) + min(diff(at))/2 * c(-1, 1)
    if (is.null(ylim)) {
      ylim <- baserange
    }
  }
  if (is.null(names)) {
    label <- 1:n
  }
  else {
    label <- names
    if (length(at) == 1) 
      at <- 1:n + at
  }
  boxwidth <- 0.05 * wex
  if (!add) 
    plot.new()
  if (!horizontal) {
    if (!add) {
      plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, las = las)
      #axis(2, las = las)
      axis(1, at = at, labels = label, las = las)
      title(main, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)
    }
    box()
    for (i in 1:n) {
      polygon(c(at[i] - height[[i]], rev(at[i] + height[[i]])), 
              c(base[[i]], rev(base[[i]])), col = col[i], border = border, 
              lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
      if (drawRect) {
        if (deciles) 
          for (j in 1:9) rect(at[i] - boxwidth * wex, 
                              decile[i, j], at[i] + boxwidth * wex, decile[i, 
                                                                           j], lwd = 0.3 * lwd)
        lines(at[c(i, i)], c(lower[i], upper[i]), lwd = lwd, 
              lty = lty)
        rect(at[i] - boxwidth * wex, q.1[i], at[i] + 
               boxwidth * wex, q.9[i], col = "transparent", 
             lty = 3)
        rect(at[i] - boxwidth/3 * wex, q1[i], at[i] + 
               boxwidth/3 * wex, q3[i], col = rectCol)
        if (any(SD.or.SE == "SD")) 
          lines(at[c(i + 0.05, i + 0.05)], c(stddevlower[i], 
                                             stddevupper[i]), lwd = lwd * 4 * wex, lty = lty)
        if (any(SD.or.SE == "SE")) 
          lines(at[c(i + 0.05, i + 0.05)], c(stderrlower[i], 
                                             stderrupper[i]), lwd = lwd * 4 * wex, lty = lty)
        points(at[i], med[i], pch = pchMed, col = colMed)
        if (CImed) 
          rect(at[i] - boxwidth/1.6 * wex, medCI05[i], 
               at[i] + boxwidth/1.6 * wex, medCI95[i])
        points(at[i], hubermu[i], pch = 12, col = colMed)
        points(at[i], average[i], pch = 13, col = colMed)
      }
      s <- seq(length(datas))
      s <- s[-length(s)]
      if (any(connect == "median")) 
        segments(at[s], med[s], at[s + 1], med[s + 1], 
                 col = connectcol[1])
      if (any(connect == "hubermu")) 
        segments(at[s], hubermu[s], at[s + 1], hubermu[s + 
                                                         1], col = connectcol[2])
      if (any(connect == "mean")) 
        segments(at[s], average[s], at[s + 1], average[s + 
                                                         1], col = connectcol[3])
      if (deciles & any(connect == "deciles")) 
        for (j in 1:9) segments(at[s], decile[s, j], 
                                at[s + 1], decile[s + 1, j], lwd = 0.6 * lwd, 
                                col = connectcol[4])
    }
  }
  else {
    if (!add) {
      plot.window(xlim = ylim, ylim = xlim, las = las)
      #axis(1, las = las)
      axis(2, at = at, labels = label, las = las)
    }
    box()
    for (i in 1:n) {
      polygon(c(base[[i]], rev(base[[i]])), c(at[i] - height[[i]], 
                                              rev(at[i] + height[[i]])), col = col[i], border = border, 
              lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
      if (drawRect) {
        if (deciles) 
          for (j in 1:9) rect(decile[i, j], at[i] - boxwidth * 
                                wex, decile[i, j], at[i] + boxwidth * wex, 
                              lwd = 0.5 * lwd)
        lines(c(lower[i], upper[i]), at[c(i, i)], lwd = lwd, 
              lty = lty)
        rect(q.1[i], at[i] - boxwidth * wex, q.9[i], 
             at[i] + boxwidth * wex, col = "transparent", 
             lty = 3)
        rect(q1[i], at[i] - boxwidth/3 * wex, q3[i], 
             at[i] + boxwidth/3 * wex, col = rectCol)
        if (any(SD.or.SE == "SD")) 
          lines(c(stddevlower[i], stddevupper[i]), at[c(i + 
                                                          0.05, i + 0.05)], lwd = lwd * 4 * wex, lty = lty)
        if (any(SD.or.SE == "SE")) 
          lines(c(stderrlower[i], stderrupper[i]), at[c(i + 
                                                          0.05, i + 0.05)], lwd = lwd * 4 * wex, lty = lty)
        if (CImed) 
          rect(medCI05[i], at[i] - boxwidth/1.6 * wex, 
               medCI95[i], at[i] + boxwidth/1.6 * wex)
        points(med[i], at[i], pch = pchMed, col = colMed)
        points(average[i], at[i], pch = 13, col = colMed)
      }
      s <- seq(length(datas))
      s <- s[-length(s)]
      if (any(connect == "median")) 
        segments(med[s], at[s], med[s + 1], at[s + 1], 
                 col = connectcol[1])
      if (any(connect == "hubermu")) 
        segments(hubermu[s], at[s], hubermu[s + 1], at[s + 
                                                         1], col = connectcol[2])
      if (any(connect == "mean")) 
        segments(average[s], at[s], average[s + 1], at[s + 
                                                         1], col = connectcol[3])
      if (deciles & any(connect == "deciles")) 
        for (j in 1:9) segments(decile[s, j], at[s], 
                                decile[s + 1, j], at[s + 1], lwd = 0.6 * lwd, 
                                col = connectcol[4])
    }
  }
  if (stats) {
    if (all(quantiles == c(0, 0))) 
      quantiles = c(0.25, 0.75)
    stats(x, by, quantiles)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean a function from the `caroline` package.
You may disable the `y` axis by changing this graphical parameter manually. This new setting will be recognized by the `axis()` functions, which is called internally by `violins()` at some step of plotting.

```
library(caroline)
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(100,0,1),y=rnorm(100,1,1),z=rnorm(100,2,3))
par(yaxt='n')
violins(df)
```

Unfortunately, many graphical parameters in `violins()` seem to be hard-coded. I you want different axes, disable them with `par()` and then call `axis()` manually with your favourite settings.